# Facebook request_ids loses when ask for permission using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the following code to ask for permissions:

```
if ($user_id) {}
 else {
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'basic_info,email,publish_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_name'

);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    }
```

The problem is that when user A invites user B, and user B accepts the invitation, a grant for permission dialog opens and then leads user B to an url like:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_name/?code=AQDf1hcI9eKBRHVI8Yo9wI5tahp6...
```

If user B already has granted permissions, the **normal** url is:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_name/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=1462567187288165&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request
```

So my question is: **How to redirect the user back to the normal url after he grants permissions?**

Comment: if ($user_id) {$params = array('redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_name')}
 else {
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'basic_info,email,publish_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_name'
);

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I need to get the request_ids from the url, but its lost after the grant for permission dialog.

Comment: You could put the request ids into the session before you send the user to the login dialog. Or you could try and set the URL including the request_ids parameter as `redirect_uri`.

Comment: I've tried with session but it didn't work, and I don't know why. If you can write how it should be done as an answer I would be very grateful :)

Comment: It worked with Session, thanks :)